# Are there verbs that means "emitting a sound"?

Tags: word-request, onomatopoeia

I am not sure if there are slang verbs that allows you to say "emit a sound" in a shorter and more conversational way. A verb like that would be useful when you tell jokes or want to have some form of informal conversation. Is there any such word?

For example:

> The guy started running with a pack of biscuits so that his dogs ___
>   "woof woof" in the backyward.

Comment: Did you mean "backyard"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English, the natural way to say that something emitted a particular sound is to use the sound as a verb.  This is one form of onomatopoeia.  For example:

> The guy started running with a pack of biscuits, so his dogs barked in the backyard.
>
> The guy started running with a pack of biscuits, so his dogs barked "woof woof" in the backyard.
>
> The guy started running with a pack of biscuits, so his dogs woof-woofed in the backyard.

Answer (score 0):

There are many I think. For example: 
utter - 
fart -
burp - 
clap - 
cluck - 
bark.

For questions like this you should use a reverse dictionary - it's silly to ask such questions here when you can easily find answers online.
https://www.onelook.com/thesaurus/?s=to%20emit%20a%20sound